# How many spell slots does a Level 3 Warlock have?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, character-advancement, character-levels, spell-slots

The Warlock Table in the PHB (p106) states that a Warlock has the following:

- 1 First-level spell slot at level 1.
- 2 First-level spell slots at level 2.
- 2 Second-level spell slots at level 3.

Does this mean that a third level Warlock has a cumulative 5 Spell Slots? (3 First-Level slots and 2 Second-Level slots)

Or do the new slots just replace old slots between levels such that a 3rd-level Warlock ultimately has only 2 second-level spell slots?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The explanation of spell slots is shown on page 107 of the PHB:

> **SPELL SLOTS**

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have.
> The table also shows what the level of those slots is; all
> of your spell slots are the same level. To cast one of your
> warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a
> spell slot. You regain all expended spell slots when you
> finish a short or long rest.

> For example, when you are 5th level, you have
> two 3rd-level spell slots. To cast the 3rd-level spell
> *thunderwave*, you must spend one of those slots, and
> you cast it as a 3rd-level spell.

So at 3rd level, you have 2 slots, you know 4 spells and you cast them as 2nd level spells.

Answer (score 6):

Warlocks have a number of slots shown on the Warlock Table, and a single slot level for all of those slots. Based on at least what you showed, at level 3 the Warlock has 2 Spell Slots, both of which are Second Level. Those are not slots they *gain*, but replace the slots they *had*.

Comment: So, a 20th level Warlock can only cast 4 spells?